# Typescript and web3 Batch Requests

Tags: typescript, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to send a batch request of transactions to my contract from web3. Using Typechain, my contract's methods are of type `NonPayableTransactionObject<void>`, which doesn't appear to support typing for that pesky `.request` method required of `batch.add()`. For example...

```
let batch = new web3.eth.BatchRequest();
for (let id of tokenIDs) {
    batch.add(myContract.methods.myMethod(id).send.request({ from: defaultAccount })   
}
batch.execute();
```

This produces `Property 'request' does not exist on type '(tx?: NonPayableTx | undefined) => PromiEvent<TransactionReceipt>'.ts(2339)`.

Is there another way of sending transactions to a contract via Batch Request using Typescript/Typechain?

Answer (score 0):

TypeChain doesn't have type declarations for the `.request` methods neither in `.send` nor in `.call` methods. But as `TypeChain` is just the type definition, the method `.request` is still available in runtime. To prevent the TS compiler to throw the error, you can simply cast the `.send` method to `any`:

```js
batch.add((myContract.methods.myMethod(id).send as any).request({ from: defaultAccount });
```

---

Another option to use statically typed Contract Classes in TypeScript is the [`0xweb`](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) library.

You generate the class with `0xweb install 0x.... --chain eth --name MyContract` and then call read methods in batch:

```js
import { MyContract } from '@dequanto/eth/MyContract'

const myContract = new MyContract();
const requests = tokenIds.map(id => {
    return myContract
        .$config({ send: 'manual', from:'0x...'})
        .myMethod(id);
});
const results = await myContract.$executeBatch(requests);
```